# how to use regex variable in zsh?

Tags: regex, bash, posix, zsh

How can I use a regex variable in zsh the same way it works in bash? I can only get zsh to work with an inline regex. I am just trying to test a string only contains alphanumerics, underscores or periods, but no dashes. As you can see, the inline regex and the regex variable work as expected in bash, but zsh only matches the inline regex.

## Bash

```
#!/bin/bash

RE='[0-9A-Za-z_\.]'

for test in $@; do
    echo -e "bash test: $test"

    if [[ "${test//[0-9A-Za-z_\.]/}" = "" ]]; then
        echo -e '\tmatch inline'
    fi

    if [[ "${test//$RE/}" = "" ]]; then
        echo -e '\tmatch var'
    fi

done
```

❯./bash-regex-test.sh foo_bar foo-bar

output:

```
bash test: foo_bar
        match inline
        match var
bash test: foo-bar
```

## Zsh

```
#!/bin/zsh


RE='[0-9A-Za-z_\.]'

for test in $@; do
    echo "zsh test: $test"

    if [[ "${test//[0-9A-Za-z_\.]/}" = "" ]]; then
        echo '\tmatch inline'
    fi

    if [[ "${test//$RE/}" = "" ]]; then
        echo '\tmatch var'
    fi

done
```

❯./zsh-regex-test.zsh foo_bar foo-bar

output:

```
zsh test: foo_bar
        match inline
zsh test: foo-bar
```

Comment: I find your question unclear. In `${test//[0-9A-Za-z_\.]/}`, the expression `[0-9A-Za-z_\.]` is not a regex, but a glob. The difference does not matter in this simple case, but it would, if you want one day to use "real" regular expressions. Therefore please be specific whether you want to talk about regular expressions or glob pattern. Your bash example would not work for regular expressions for instance.

Answer (score 14):

With `zsh` you need to use `${~RE}` instead of `$RE` so the variable `$RE`
is treated as a pattern, not the literal string. Then change the line as:

```
    if [[ "${test//${~RE}/}" = "" ]]; then
```

BTW your usage of `$RE` is not the *regex* but the *pattern* as in
pathname expansion.
In  order to use it as a regex, you'll need to use `=~` operator as:

```
#!/bin/zsh

RE='^[0-9A-Za-z_\.]+$'

for test in "$@"; do
    echo "zsh test: $test"

    if [[ $test =~ ^[0-9A-Za-z_\.]+$ ]]; then
        echo '\tmatch inline'
    fi

    if [[ $test =~ $RE ]]; then
        echo '\tmatch var'
    fi

done
```

Comment: `${~sub}` replacement is covered in the "Expansion" > 14.3 "Parameter Expansion > "${name/pattern/repl}" section of the `zsh` documentation. See: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html

Comment: @tshiono - Thanks and why the double '[[' in 'if [[ "${test//${~RE}/}" = "" ]]; then'? - interested, rather than any knowledge here :)